# Cannot evaluate a two-digit number

Tags: java, for-loop, evaluate

I have a `evaluate` method that so far adds, subtracts, and multiplies strings (e.g. "5*5"). However, when I try to evaluate a single digit by a triple digit ("5*10"), it returns "5" instead of "50". I think my problem is that it's only taking the first string of the double digit and evaluating accordingly. Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
public double evaluate(String exp){
        String left = "";
        String right = "";
        double leftValue = 0;
        double rightValue = 0;
        double answer = 0;
        //ensures expression matches an appropriate expression (i.e. 2+2, not "2"
        if(exp.length()==1)
        {
            //if single digit, return double value
            return Double.parseDouble(exp);
        }
        //searching for a "+"
        for(int i=0;i<exp.length();i++)
        {
            if(exp.charAt(i)=='+')
            {
                right = exp.substring(i+1, exp.length());
                leftValue = subtract(left);
                rightValue = evaluate(right);
                answer = leftValue + rightValue;
                return answer;
            }   
            else
            {
                left = left + exp.substring(i,(i+1));

            }

        } // End for loop
        answer = subtract(exp);
        return answer;
    } // End evaluate method

    // Guaranteed there are no addition operators in exp 
    public double subtract(String exp){
        String leftString = "";
        String rightString = "";
        double leftValue = 0;
        double rightValue = 0;
        double answer = 0;

        for(int i=exp.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            if(exp.charAt(i)=='-')
            {
                // Convert rightString into Double
                rightValue = Double.parseDouble(rightString);
                leftString = exp.substring(0,i);
                leftValue=subtract(leftString);
                answer = leftValue - rightValue;
                return answer;
            }   
            else
            // Accumulating the right string
            {
                rightString = rightString + exp.substring(i,(i+1));
            }
        } // End for loop
        answer= multiply(exp);

        return answer;

...then the code goes onto multiplication, etc....

    } // End evaluate method
```

Comment: is it must to do in this way? you can do this in much easier way

Comment: Let's put @StinePike's comment another way. You're doing it wrong. You may fix this trivial error but you'll then hit other more serious hurdles: operator precedence and parentheses, whereupon you'll have to start all over again. Do it now. You need to look up 'recursive descent expression parser' and 'Dijkstra shunting-yard algorithm'.

Comment: @user2297666: If one of the answers below helped you solve your problem or addresses your question, please mark it as accepted, so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to spot it easily.

Comment: @user2297666: Hm...judging from most of your questions, you seem to have something against marking an answer as "accepted" ! May I ask why ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ScriptEngine class and evaluate it as a javascript string

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");        
Object result = engine.eval("5*10");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `subtract` method you "build" the `rightString` String "backwards", i.e. converting `5*10` to `01*5` = 5.
You probably need to change that:

```
// Accumulating the right string
{
    rightString = rightString + exp.substring(i,(i+1));
}
```

to this:

```
// Accumulating the right string
{
    rightString = exp.substring(i,(i+1)) + rightString;
}
```